# converting ASCII text to jpg image

Tags: hex, jpeg, converters

I am trying to convert an ascii text to a jpg image. When I use the unix `file myFile.jpg` command, it gives`myFile.jpg: ASCII text, with very long lines`.

I have tried to use online text to jpg converters but to no avail. I am pretty sure the flag is of jpg format because it starts with ffd8 and ends with ffd9.

The ascii hex of the image starts like `ff d8 ff e0 00 ....`

I tried to use the online converters but it didn't work. I'm not sure how I could do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, but no success. What I did was to copy the ASCII text/art into an text area in Photoshop (should of course work with any other tool like Photoshop). Then changed the font to Consolas. After that I could save the result as an image file.

Comment: topic starter was asking how to convert HEX-data he has to an actual image that was coded: not an image with ASCII art...